# GAE blobstore get image size error

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery-file-upload

I use GAE/J blobstore to upload images, I found in most cases it works just fine, but sometimes getting the image size give me wrong value:

```
...
BlobInfo info = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
long size = info.getSize();
```

Say, I have a jpg image, it's size is 141KB with dimension 236 x 1580, but after uploading to blobstore, the size is just about 60KB(the dimension is wrong too), other images which bigger than 141KB can get uploaded fine and can get correct size at server side.

I'm not sure it's GAE problem or not, Could someone shed some light on this? Thanks

BTW i use jquery-file-upload at client side, with a max uploaded image size set to 5Mb.

Comment: I doubt that this is related to GAE. There is nothing in the BlobStore related to 141KB number.

Comment: But how to explain why others succeed and this one failed? one note is that the height of image is 1580, which is larger than other images which succeed.

Comment: Blobstore does not know that you store an image. It's just a blob of data. What do you mean when you say, "the dimension is wrong too"?

Comment: I am seeing this at the moment too. The dimensions are wrong i.e. width and height. This is when using the serving url. I toss back the image data through a python script though (base64 json etc) and my API per se still works without problem; I just use serving url for admin interface - which looks incorrect now. It works on localhost though when testing.